# Is it possible to create a web based VNC/RDP-like client and server without use of plugins?

Tags: web, rdp, vnc

Assuming there is a publically available relay is there a way to create both a VNC/RDP-like client and server without using plugins/extensions or being browser specific? (e.g. no flash, no java, no active-x, etc). Or do all browser's security models void this scenario unless plugins are involved?

e.g.

1. user who has an issue navigates to url and starts a server instance within the browser
2. support rep navigates to same url but as client and then sees users computer.

Comment: Is it possible to create VS is there open source code available. What is your question - but be warned, any question regarding find a tool or a source will be closed.

Comment: Available open source code would be a bonus but the heart of my question is whether it is possible to make a VNC/RDP-like app that's purely web based without plugins? (And if so.. what technology would I use? Web sockets? WebGL? etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As a browser uses a sandbox to run applications that detaches from the native system environment there is no way to create a server inside a website that serves the UI of the system-environment.

Even if you find a way to break out of the sandbox in specific browsers, you might not be browser compatible.

Even if you find a way to break out of the sandbox of every browser, you need a native part to interpret the framebuffer of the server-machine.

I stop here thinking because it is getting to many phantastic violations.

Comment: Doesn't webgl API allow you access to some aspects of video card functionality regardless of platform?

Comment: VNC allowes to use mouse and keyboard what is not part of WebGL.